# kinetic.js html5 "animals on beach" example

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I can't for the life of me understand what the problem is here.

I've copied the code verbatim from the following link: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-animals-on-the-beach-game-with-kineticjs/

After doing so, I replaced some of the variables with my own (and created my own images) for the custom interactivity:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #06F;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.0.1.min.js"></script>

    <script defer>
      function loadImages(sources, callback) {
        var assetDir = 'http://www.darnellcreates.com/GeneralTesting/DCSummer/works/interactive/img/';
        var images = {};
        var loadedImages = 0;
        var numImages = 0;
        for(var src in sources) {
          numImages++;
        }
        for(var src in sources) {
          images[src] = new Image();
          images[src].onload = function() {
            if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
              callback(images);
            }
          };
          images[src].src = assetDir + sources[src];
        }
      }
      function isNearOutline(puzzlepiece, outline) {
        var a = puzzlepiece;
        var o = outline;
        var ax = a.getX();
        var ay = a.getY();

        if(ax > o.x - 20 && ax < o.x + 20 && ay > o.y - 20 && ay < o.y + 20) {
          return true;
        }
        else {
          return false;
        }
      }
      function drawBackground(background, tableImg, text) {
        var context = background.getContext();

        context.drawImage(tableImg, 0, 0);
        context.setAttr('font', '20pt Calibri');
        context.setAttr('textAlign', 'center');
        context.setAttr('fillStyle', 'white');
        context.fillText(text, background.getStage().getWidth() / 2, 40);
      }
      function initStage(images) {
        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
          container: 'container',
          width: 600,
          height: 500
        });
        var background = new Kinetic.Layer();
        var puzzlepieceLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
        var puzzlepieceShapes = [];
        var score = 0;

        // image positions
        var puzzlepieces = {
          piece1: {
            x: 10,
            y: 70
          },
          piece2: {
            x: 90,
            y: 70
          },
          piece4: {
            x: 275,
            y: 70
          },
          piece3: {
            x: 400,
            y: 70
          },
        };

        var outlines = {
          piece1_black: {
            x: 275,
            y: 350
          },
          piece2_black: {
            x: 390,
            y: 250
          },
          piece4_black: {
            x: 300,
            y: 420
          },
          piece3_black: {
            x: 100,
            y: 390
          },
        };

        // create draggable puzzlepieces
        for(var key in puzzlepieces) {
          // anonymous function to induce scope
          (function() {
            var privKey = key;
            var piece = puzzlepieces[key];

            var puzzlepiece = new Kinetic.Image({
              image: images[key],
              x: piece.x,
              y: piece.y,
              draggable: true,
              brightness: 0,
              blurRadius: 0
            });

            puzzlepiece.cache();
            puzzlepiece.drawHitFromCache();
            puzzlepiece.filters([
              Kinetic.Filters.Blur,
              Kinetic.Filters.Brighten
            ]);

            puzzlepiece.on('dragstart', function() {
              this.moveToTop();
              puzzlepieceLayer.draw();
            });
            /*
             * check if puzzlepiece is in the right spot and
             * snap into place if it is
             */
            puzzlepiece.on('dragend', function() {
              var outline = outlines[privKey + '_black'];
              if(!puzzlepiece.inRightPlace && isNearOutline(puzzlepiece, outline)) {
                puzzlepiece.setPosition({x:outline.x, y:outline.y});
                puzzlepieceLayer.draw();
                puzzlepiece.inRightPlace = true;


                if(++score >= 4) {
                  var text = 'You win! Enjoy your booty!'
                  drawBackground(background, images.table, text);
                }

                // disable drag and drop
                setTimeout(function() {
                  puzzlepiece.setDraggable(false);
                }, 50);
              }
            });
            // make puzzlepiece glow on mouseover
            puzzlepiece.on('mouseover touchstart', function() {
              puzzlepiece.blurRadius(1);
              puzzlepiece.brightness(0.3);
              puzzlepieceLayer.draw();
              document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
            });
            // return puzzlepiece on mouseout
            puzzlepiece.on('mouseout touchend', function() {
              puzzlepiece.blurRadius(0);
              puzzlepiece.brightness(0);
              puzzlepieceLayer.draw();
              document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
            });

            puzzlepiece.on('dragmove', function() {
              document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
            });

            puzzlepieceLayer.add(puzzlepiece);
            puzzlepieceShapes.push(puzzlepiece);
          })();
        }

        // create puzzlepiece outlines
        for(var key in outlines) {
          // anonymous function to induce scope
          (function() {
            var imageObj = images[key];
            var out = outlines[key];

            var outline = new Kinetic.Image({
              image: imageObj,
              x: out.x,
              y: out.y,
               draggable: true,
            });

            puzzlepieceLayer.add(outline);
          })();
        }

        stage.add(background);
        stage.add(puzzlepieceLayer);

        drawBackground(background, images.table, 'Ahoy! Put the puzzlepieces on the table!');
      }

      var sources = {
        table: 'Help-Grid.png',
        piece1: 'piece1.png',
        piece1_black: 'piece1-black.png',
        piece3: 'piece3.png',
        piece3_black: 'piece3-black.png',
        piece4: 'piece4.png',
        piece4_black: 'piece4-black.png',
        piece2: 'piece2.png',
        piece2_black: 'piece2-black.png',
      };
      loadImages(sources, initStage);


    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, with that being said, everything checks out like it should. I validated the javascript using http://esprima.org/demo/validate.html and it passed with no errors. Same with the plugin...

Strange thing, is that it works fine within the actual link I provided above and in Adobe Dreamweaver...but not in any browser! Even if you take the page and save it as a HTML, associate all paths to css/js accordingly, no results...anyone have any idea here?

PS: I've tried the different versions of the Kinetic.js plugin (newest to oldest) and seems nothing works...

```
  [1]: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-animals-on-the-beach-game-with-kineticjs/
```

Comment: One clue, you are able to drag your gray puzzlepiece outlines rather then the full-color pieces (that's backwards).  Since you've only made minor adjustments to the original code I would restart with the original code and (1) change the images (2) test (3) if that works change the var-names (single step the var name changes--you probably renamed something you shouldn't have)

Comment: Well it's strange, because if you copy the HTML provided in the example and save it as a document, it doesn't work at all. It only seems to work in Dreamweaver and on the example URL page.

Comment: To your original point, I added the variable "draggable: true" in the following: var outline = new Kinetic.Image({
              image: imageObj,
              x: out.x,
              y: out.y,
  draggable:true,    
            });
 portion in the above example, which is why the outlines drag. Strangely enough, the pieces w/color have "draggable: true" set on them, yet it does nothing.

Comment: Yep, the original tutorial is broken. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Easy.

Copy this line of code and put it at line 40 or 41 in your above code.

```
console.log(ax, o.x, ay, o.y);
```

That goes right after the variable definitions of the function 'isNearOutline'

Comment: Obviously if the results are for instance (334, 300, 2, 420) then the last two numbers (the 'y' variables) are never going to be within a tolerance of '20'. You have to figure out why they are that far off... clearly that's not what you intended... (NOTE: I was dragging a piece that should have fit right where it was)

Comment: Also remember, most kinetic shapes will ahve their 'zero' points ({x:0, y:0}) at the top left most point of a bounding box of all the contained points of the shape. So for a square, that's the top left corner. For a puzzle piece, it might be in the top left corner 'up in blank space' depending on the shape of the piece. When I create my kinetic shapes, I usually put the 'zero' coordinates at the center of the shape. That takes a bit of work. Not sure if that's also playing in to your X coordinate issue. let me know if I need to spend more time on this.

Comment: JSdc, thank you for your reply. Perhaps I'm a bit wacky sans my coffee this morning, but I've copied the "console.log(ax, o.x, ay, o.y);" portion into the area and nothing came out of it. Did a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phaxj/